# Using of SQLite TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of null

Tags: ionic4

I use ionic4 + angular8 code flow:

[image]

Error code:

[image]

Please help me. Thank you.

error code in here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJxn0.png)

Comment: webService.service.ts and storageService.service.ts are 2 files that you created right ?can you post 2 file webService.service.ts and storageService.service.ts ?

Comment: webService.service.ts和storageService.service.ts？ no problem.  subject matter is sqlite

Answer (score 1):

You have written **transaction** but, I let you know that there is no property of transaction in SQLite plugin, you need to add write create property, whatever to open or create the database. like =>

```
this.sqlite.create({
  name: 'data.db',
  location: 'default'
})
  .then((db: SQLiteObject) => 

db.executeSql('create table danceMoves(name VARCHAR(32))', [])
  .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
  })

  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open or create db from sqlite , you should use executeSql after to execute query and take action with db. Sqlite for ionic 4 doesn't support transaction anymore. 
[For more information and example](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite)

```
this.sqlite.create({
  name: 'data.db',
  location: 'default'
})
  .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {


    db.executeSql('create table danceMoves(name VARCHAR(32))', [])
      .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));


  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```